# How do you use 'where' for a parameter that has a hash of values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In my db I have a column that takes a hash of values. How do I use where to get to the values?

So if I have this

```
<PublicActivity::Activity id: 87, trackable_id: 1, trackable_type: "User", owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User", key: "shout.like", parameters: {:id=>"1187467057945665_1220996764592694", :provider=>"github"}, recipient_id: 1, recipient_type: "User", created_at: "2015-10-12 19:07:16", updated_at: "2015-10-12 19:07:16">
```

How do I find all the records with provider: "github"? I can't find the notation on how this is done.

I've tried this but I keep getting an empty array

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where(parameters: 'github')
```

Comment: What type of DB are you using and what column type is `parameters`?

Comment: ...because depending on that the answer will be "use database-specific operations" or "you can't, at least not reliably".

Comment: Using ActiveRecord and parameters is 'text'. Also, using sqlite in development and mysql in production

Comment: So you're using `serialize :parameters` in your model and now you want to query inside `parameters`? This is why you don't use `serialize`. Break your `parameters` out to a separate table so that you're not dealing with a big nasty blob of YAML inside a text column.

Answer (score 0):

if you use PostgreSQL use the following syntax to search for Hash serialized:

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where("parameters -> 'provider' = 'github'")
```

OR:

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where("parameters @> 'provider=>github'")
```

to get all records where parameters contain the provider key:

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where("parameters ? 'provider'")
```

Comment: Ok. How do you do this for mysql or sqlite though?

Comment: Rather than jump in with an answer using a specific DBM, it'd be more appropriate to ask what DBM is being used (since the OP didn't say until after you answered), and then formulate an answer specific to it.

Comment: There is no way to do it that's database-independent. There is no standard SQL way to store a hash in a single column and then query keys of that hash. If you are just using ActiveRecord serialize to yaml, you can't do it. You can do it with some database-specific features, like the built-in Postgres feature mentioned above.